# Laravel 5.4 return a pdf download

Tags: laravel

basically I have a question,

How do I generate a pdf download on my controller's return. What i mean is, in my controller im fetching data and would like to pass it to my pdf blade view, so on the return part, is it possible to download my pdf?

Generally in a normal blade view, we pass teh data via; `return view('admin.log_actions', compact('logs'));` for example. So is it possible to set it like `return pdf(pdf_route, compact(data));` ?

Comment: have you tried this package. [A DOMPDF Wrapper for Laravel](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf). This is what I usually use to convert data into pdf

Comment: gotcha, thanks for the input!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't have the pdf document yet.

Download this package: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf

And use the following code.

```
$pdf = PDF::loadView('pdfs.my-pdf-view', $data);

return $pdf->download('name.pdf');
```

If you have the pdf file already, you can use the `response()->file()` helper.

```
return response()->file($filePath);
```

Comment: yep this is the answer